# How do i match the value which has a radio button checked

Tags: xpath

I have a list of similar looking DIVs without any Div ID, except one has a check box checked and others doesn't. What i need is to find the value from a child tag only if a radio button is selected.
Below is a simpler version of my code.

```
<div class = "XYZ">
    <input type="radio" checked>
    <input type="hidden" value="This is a great thing 1"> 
</div>

<div class = "XYZ">
    <input type="radio">
    <input type="hidden" value="This is a great thing 2"> 
</div>
```

Result needed is

```
This is a great thing 1
```

Unfortunately the source code cannot be changed.

Comment: `Unable to parse any XML input. Attribute name "checked" associated with an element type "input" must be followed by the ' = ' character.`

Answer (score 0):

Your xpath should look for a `div` that contains the checked `input` and to get the value for the one that has value attribute.

First selector returns the input, the second returns the value.

```
//div[.//input[@checked]]/input[@value]

//div[.//input[@checked]]/input/@value
```

As an alternative you can use the following sibling:

```
//input[@checked]/following-sibling::input
```

If you want to also use the class of the parent div:

```
//div[@class='XYZ']/input[@checked]/following-sibling::input
```